# Conditional build of static library which more then one executable depends on in qmake

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, build-system

I have subdir project :

```
//exaple.pro
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
myLib \
executable_one \
executable_two
```

`myLib` is static library with one function in it:

```
//MyLib.h
void foo();

//MyLib.cpp
#include "MyLib.h"
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
#   ifdef MY_DEFINE
        std::cout << "MY_DEFINE is defined\n";
#   else
        std::cout << "MY_DEFINE is undefined\n";
#   endif
}
```

And two other projects which are linking to this library `executable_one` and `executable_two`. In one I want to define `MY_DEFINE`, in another one don't. So I've tried to add `DEFINES += MY_DEFINE` in the `executable_one.pro` file, but in both cases the output is "MY_DEFINE is undefined". I understand that `myLib` was compiled without this flag before executable and then was just linked into it without changing, but is there any way to make the library be built twice and for one of the executables pass this compiler option to the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way you can achieve this without compiling `myLib` twice.

You must build the library twice (easiest is to have two .pro file for the library), one with `DEFINES += MY_DEFINE` one without. Then, the two .pro files must define a different target (one could be `myLib_my_define`, the other one, `myLib_no_my_define`).

Later `executable_one` will link with `myLib_my_define`, and `executable_two` will link with `myLib_no_my_define`.

Obviously, an alternative is toi replace your pre-processing variable by a regular variable (have `foo` take a boolean variable for the switch), but I suppose it's not possible to do that if you asked the question the way you asked it.

Comment: Finally I've decided to rename `myLib.pro` to `myLib.pri`, create two pro files `myLibWithDef.pro` and `myLibWithoutDef.pro`. In both I've included `myLib.pri` and in one of them I've added `DEFINES += MY_DEFINE`.

Comment: Perfect, I don't use .pri file very often but it's a nice way to fix your issue here.